# Finding all integers that exist in list1 that don't exist in list2 with fewest lines of code?

Tags: c#, list

Let's say I have two lists of integers:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6};
List<int> list2 = new List<int> {4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

What is the quickest way to find all of the integers that exist in list1 but not list2

The simplest solution I can think of is to create a union list from list1 and list2 and remove all of the members from this union that exist in list2

```
Union = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
Union - list2 = {1,2,3} <- This is my desired result
```

But maybe there is a simpler and faster one line of code way to get this job done?

Comment: Can the lists have duplicates?

Comment: Yea, list1 {1,1,1,2}, list2 {2,3,3,3}, items in list1 not in list2 {1,1,1}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list1.Except(list2)` (if using .NET 3.5)

Comment: I knew this type of thing existed! :)  Is there a link to a page with all of these list comparison extension methods?  I learned of union recently, and I think it would be useful to know these in the future.

Comment: @sooprise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx is a good starting point - or read my Edulinq blog series for details: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Comment: This will not return duplicates.

Comment: Is there an extension method that will return duplicates?

Comment: You're right, but duplicates were not part of the original question.  That is an important fact to omit.  LukeH's answer will work then.

Answer (score 2):

If the lists can potentially contain duplicate elements and you want to return any duplicates from `list1` then you can do something like this:

```
var tempSet = new HashSet<int>(list2);
var results = list1.Where(x => !tempSet.Contains(x));
```

If `list2` only contains a few elements then you can probably get away without using a `HashSet<T>`:

```
var results = list1.Where(x => !list2.Contains(x));
```

Though for larger collections you'll find that the `HashSet<T>` will easily outperform using the list directly: `Contains` is O(1) for `HashSet<T>` and O(n) for arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` sequences.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed, `Select` was a mistake. I meant `Where`. Updated.